# How to bootstrap generated files task output with msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

I have a [`.csproj`](https://github.com/UiPath/orchestrator-powershell/blob/v18.1.3.1/UiPath.Web.Client/UiPath.Web.Client.csproj) file where I declare some generated files:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AutoGenerated Include="generated\*.cs;generated\Models\*.cs"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

This is used as `Outputs` on a task:

```
<Target Name="GenerateFilesFromTemplate" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild;BeforeRebuild"
        Inputs="sometemplatefile"
        Outputs="@(AutoGenerated)">
    <Exec
        Command="somegenerator.exe ... "
        Outputs="@(AutoGenerated)"/>
</Target>
```

The `generated/` is added .gitignore, so the generated files are not part of the source control.

My problem is that this setup does not bootstrap itself. As initially the `generated` folder is empty, the build skips the generate files task because it has no outputs:

```
GenerateFilesFromTemplate:
Skipping target "GenerateFilesFromTemplate" because it has no outputs.
```

I feel I'm doing this the wrong way, or I'm missing the obvious. I know I can remove the `Inputs` and `Outputs` on the `Task` and then it will generate the files on every build. But the generation is lengthy, and I want to avoid it if no necessary (the template file did not change). How can I make the build self-bootstrap and generate the files on first build, or when necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output items are meant to indicate **known** output files of a target. MSBuild then checks if all modification dates of the outputs are greater than the highest modification date of the input items to see if it can skip the target. It will also run the target if one of the outputs are missing.

If you cannot know in advance which files are generated by a target, a workaround is to produce a temporary file with a known location.

e.g. write use the `WriteLinesToFile` task (configured to overwrite) to update a file (`$(IntermediateOutputPath)autogen.marker`) and use the file as output element. It will then run the target on the first build and then only run if the input template file is newer than the marker.

Comment: Thanks. I used one of the known generated files as `Outputs` and this works fine.